# parse and echo string in a bash while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a file with this structure:

```
picture1_123.txt
picture2_456.txt
picture3_789.txt
picture4_012.txt
```

I wanted to get only the first segment of the file name, that is, picture1 to picture4.
I first used the following code:

```
cat picture | while read -r line; do cut -f1 -d "_"; echo $line; done
```

This returns the following output:

```
picture2
picture3
picture4
picture1_123.txt
```

This error got corrected when I changed the code to the following:

```
cat picture | while read line; do s=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d "_"); echo $s; done

picture1
picture2
picture3
picture4
```

Why in the first:

1. The lines are printed in a different order than the original file?
2. no operation is done on picture1_123.txt and picture1 is not printed?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `cut` command is reading the entire rest of stdin, so nothing is left for the next `read` command.

Comment: ...if you wanted it to `cut` contents in `line` only, and save the result back to `line`, that might instead be `line=$(cut -f1 -d "_" <<<"$line")` -- but don't do that, starting a new copy of `cut` per line of input is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Also, note that `echo $line` is itself buggy. Always, **always** quote your expansions, as in `echo "$line"`; see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) -- or try testing with a file named `*_foo.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What Was Wrong

Here's what your old code did:

- On the first (and only) iteration of the loop, `read line` read the first line into `line`.
- The `cut` command read the *entire rest of the file*, and wrote the results of extracting only the desired field to stdout. It did not inspect, read, or modify the `line` variable.
- Finally, your `echo $line` wrote the first line in entirety, with nothing being cut.
- Because all input had been consumed by `cut`, nothing remained for the next `read line` to consume, so the loop never ran a second time.

---

#### How To Do It Right

The simple way to do this is to let `read` separate out your prefix:

```
while IFS=_ read -r prefix suffix; do
  echo "$prefix"
done <picture
```

...or to just run nothing but `cut`, and not use any `while read` loop at all:

```
cut -f1 -d_ <picture
```